# How can I solve this integral? (Hilbert transform of a Gaussian)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, gaussian-integral, cauchy-principal-value

As a follow-up to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230917/why-does-mathematica-give-the-wrong-answer-for-this-integral-and-how-can-i-corr?noredirect=1#comment585479_230917) question about Mathematica's (in)ability to solve the following integral, I am curious how to solve it analytically:

$$\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-x}dt=-2\sqrt\pi F(x),$$

where $x\in\mathbb R,$ $F$ is the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function#Definition) defined by $F(x)=e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-u^2}du$, $\operatorname{PV}$ denotes the Cauchy principal value at $x$, namely, the limit as $\epsilon\to0+$ of the integral over $\mathbb R\setminus(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon).$

I am comfortable with complex analysis, but not Schwartz distributions. There is a proof of this identity in the "Dawson function" Wikipedia link above, but it assumes knowledge of distributions and uses the identity $\frac{1}{u}=\int_0^\infty \sin(ku)dk$, which I am not going to accept casually. I suspect a contour integral + residue theory approach might be possible.

Comment: You could probably use the intertwining property with the Fourier transform, a la $$\mathcal{F}\mathcal{H} f(x) = -i\operatorname{sgn}(x)\mathcal{F}f(x),$$ or equivalently, $$\mathcal{H}f(x) = -i\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)\mathcal{F}f)(x).$$ Note that part of this computation is trivial since the Gaussian is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform.

Comment: You can regularize the identity you cannot accept by adding an exponentially decaying factor. The rest of derivation remains intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my own method that doesn't involve complex analysis or Fourier transforms. Just a bit of trickery with commuting derivatives and limits with integrals, which could actually be justified with convergence theorems from measure theory that I will neglect:

---

First, convert the integral to a different form:

$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-x}dt\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-x}dt
+\int_{x+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-x}dt\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(-\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(t-x)^2}}{t}dt
+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(t+x)^2}}{t}dt\right)\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{-e^{-(t-x)^2}+e^{-(t+x)^2}}{t}dt\\\\
&=-2e^{-x^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(2xt)}{t}e^{-t^2}dt\\\\
\end{align}$

Now the remaining integral can be solved by differentiating under the integral sign:

$\begin{align}
J(x)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(2xt)}{t}e^{-t^2}dt\\\\
J'(x)&=2\int_0^\infty\cosh(2xt)e^{-t^2}dt\\\\
&=\sqrt\pi\,e^{x^2}
\end{align}$

where the previous step comes from expanding the $\cosh$ as exponentials and completing the squares to obtain simple Gaussians. Then we have:

$\begin{align}
J(x)&=J(0)+\int_0^x J'(t)dt\\\\
&=0+\sqrt\pi\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{erfi}(x)
\end{align}$

Finally we have

$\begin{align}
I(x)&=-\pi e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erfi}(x)\\\\
&=-2\sqrt\pi F(x)
\end{align}$